# What is the keyboard combination for turbo on Prolinea 3/25?

Tags: keyboards, compaq, turbo

I have a Compaq Prolinea 3/25zs (BIOS 08/03/92 386C)and suspect it can be switched between 25 MHz and some lower speed. There's a BIOS setting for System Power-on Speed, "Auto" or "High", and someone in a forum claimed they had one of these long ago and could switch the speed using the keyboard: [The Perfect IBM PC AT](https://vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10689)

I asked if they knew the combination but didn't get an answer that worked (from another user).

I've never been able to figure out what it is. I have clone motherboards that do this with ctrl:alt:+ and ctrl:alt:-. I've tried some other combinations but none seem to do anything based on testing with a benchmark utility. I haven't been able to find the user manual for this either.

Does anyone know what key combination controls this? Or if it even has this function?

Comment: Are you talking Compaq? Also, what let you 'suspect' that this feature exists? Last but not least, it would be helpful to add the sources you're citing.

Comment: It looks like the hotkeys used depend on the BIOS, so could you edit the question with the exact BIOS version this system has?

Comment: Other things to check: See if there is a "Turbo LED" or if the Power LED has three wires so it can switch colors (which would be used to indicate turbo mode). Also, it looks like there are one-chip controller solutions that include selectable clock speed (see other question), so identify all chips on your motherboard that could potentially have this role, and look for datasheets.

Comment: It only has a power and HDD led, and the LEDs are not bi-color based on having two wires (unless they are inverse parallel...doubt it though). The closest large support chip to the CPU is a WD76C10A which has the ability to slow the CPU, page 5-21: "There are two methods for slowing the processor execution rate to provide software compatibility with programs expecting a particular CPU speed" then goes on to describe changing the divider. There is a register to set this.

Comment: Actually, switching to/fro turbo mode using the keyboard was a relatively rare feature only implemented in early AT clones.

Comment: @tofro I would not call it rare and only implemented by early AT clones, if many 486 motherboards had the feature.

Comment: @justme On a 486 system? no. Most have a jumper or switch to enable Turbo mode (if at all), but not a lot had that control on the keybord

Comment: @tofro Yes, and even some Pentium motherboards too.

Comment: @justme Can you come up with examples that had keyboard control for turbo mode?

Comment: @tofro My MG motherboard with UMC chipset, AMI WinBios and AMD 486DX4/100 had that, and apparently it was a common feature as stated in the related question here : https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28309/were-there-any-pcs-where-you-could-switch-turbo-mode-via-the-keyboard

Comment: @Justme The question you relate to asks if *any* computers have keyboard-based switching at all. You wouldn't normally derive from there that it was a "common feature". The answers to that question list XT-compatible examples. Note I'm not saying it wasn't a feature anywhere, but just a rare feature, starting with PC and XT-compatibles, but becoming more and more uncommon for 386 and 486.